# What happens when using realloc and memory is written to a new address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have a function which accepts a pointer to a struct, which is defined like so

```
typedef struct Array {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void **items;
} Array;
```

This function will realloc the memory of `array->items` to increase the size.

The function is given below

```
void doubleArray(Array *array) {
    array->capacity *= 2;
    void **items = realloc(array->items, array->capacity);
    if(items == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    array->items = items;
}
```

What I am have difficulty understanding is, if I assign `void **items` to the result of realloc, **and realloc returns a new memory address because the previous buffer has been overwritten**, does `array->items` get assigned correctly to the new value even after returning from the function?

Or will the fact that `void **items` is defined within the local scope of the function `doubleArray` mean that `array->items` becomes a dangling pointer because it is not correctly re-assigned because the reference to `void **items` is deleted once the function exits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How \`realloc\` work actually in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437482/how-realloc-work-actually-in-the-background)

Comment: @Abhineet - Not sure its a duplicate.. The question you posted talks about how `realloc` works, whereas my question is an extension of that regarding what happens to the pointer reference defined in the function that `realloc`'s return value is assigned to. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: The `realloc` won't work anyway because the size passed is incorrect. You have passed the number of elements and ignored the size of each.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Do you mind elaborating on that? I'm not really following

Comment: If there are `capacity` elements they will need more than 1 byte each. They will each need the size of a pointer.

Comment: So I suggest `void **items = realloc(array->items, array->capacity * sizeof *items);`. However it seems strange that the `struct` contains `void **items;` as this can't be doubly-dereferenced.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Would I need to do this even if `array->capacity` is an `int` and I am assigning only `int` values to `void **items`? I recognize I'm making this more complex than it needs to be, but just want to make sure I understand why this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165029/discussion-between-random-coder-101-and-weather-vane).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem of understanding is not about `realloc()`, its's about pointer and local variable in general.

> does array->items get assigned correctly to the new value even after returning from the function?

In your code above, it is correctly assigned. Although pointer points to some address, pointer **itself** is an ordinary variable.

> array->items becomes a dangling pointer because it is not correctly re-assigned because the reference to void **items is deleted once the function exits?

No. No pointer is deleted. Local variable `void **items` **itself** is out of scope, but not what it points to.

Consider:

```
void foo(Array *a) {
    int sz = 23;
    a->size = sz;
}
```

Will `a->size` become "dangling" after the function return ? Your problem is the same as this one.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you should note is, the expression:

```
void **items = realloc(array->items, array->capacity);
```

should probably be changed to:

```
void **items = realloc(array->items, (array->capacity) * sizeof(void *));
```

Secondly, to answer your question:

> does array->items get assigned correctly to the new value even after returning from the function?

Its does, because you pass a pointer (to a structure) to your function, thus the function has the ability to modify the `struct` member `items`.

Next, when you assign `array->items = items;` and the function returns, the local variable `items` runs out of scope, but remember, its value which have been assigned to `array->items`, is the address of memory that has allocated storage duration, so `array->items` is not a dangling pointer because it is  pointing to valid memory.